# How to isolate an object from its background when you have the isolated background already?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, blending

So I have multiple objects that are all on the same background but I only have them as flat images and also the background image alone, thought with some blending magic ("Difference", "Color to alpha/transparency", etc..) I would be able to isolate said objects from its background. But no luck on my part and googling didn't help me either.

I am talking of course about a half decent, automated color maths kind of thing. Sure I could extract all of them by hand but its not viable in this case.

Is there a way? Plugin maybe?

Here a kind of flowchart of my problem:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Using Difference blending mode should've been able to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove backgrond using a photo with only the background? (GIMP/others)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92218/how-to-remove-backgrond-using-a-photo-with-only-the-background-gimp-others)

Comment: (at)sergey sure enough I thought so too. I even tried it again on the example pictures i posted and it sure enough worked as expected. But I just realised, the background seems to be ever so slightly different and when I say slightly I mean it. But apparently it messes up the entire result to a degree of where its not even useful as a reference point in my case.

(at)Billy this is basically Difference blending mode in GIMP, right? I will download GIMP and try it

Comment: for some reason i cant edit my comment..
however: the GIMP solution helps a bit since the bg color is not black like in PS (color palette of this project for the images is mainly blacks, dark greyish colors, so easier selection with the GIMP way)

I would still be glad about further solutions, I just can't imagine this being the easiest way, however the GIMP solution DID help, TY

btw.. any way to change the bg/alpha color of Difference mode in PS?

Comment: Yes, the answer (for GIMP) assumes the backgrounds are exactly the same. If not then it won't really work well (as already mentioned in my answer).  This could be also done in Photoshop with a difference blending mode although the result is different with GIMP's "grain extract" which will give you a grey background.  GIMP also has a difference blending mode. However I have to say removing backgrounds using this method is not easy. It would be easier to use Photoshop's select and mask functionality, or GIMP's foreground select functionality to make a mask, but these require some manual effort.