# How to separate effects of merged layers after the fact if I have one of the layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but can't seem to, so I'm asking here.

Imagine I have an original image, like for instance this one:

[image]

Then I mess with it a bit, add some tinting, add some clouds, and get this image at the end:

[image]

However, suppose I lost the history of the changes I made, so that at the end all I have is these two images and nothing else.

Is it possible to do something that will recover a layer that basically "applies the same changes" to the original image? That is, something like an image that is equivalent to applying a hue/saturation to every pixel of the original image that gets the new image?

Of course I can't recover anything that was "background", I won't be able to figure out what's "behind" Thanatos in the second image, but I'd like to at least have some way to regenerate the "mist" and the "tinting" that are in front of/on top of Thanatos so that I can generate the green tint and misty effects on him starting from the original image again. I had hoped that messing around with difference or subtraction layers and all that jazz would help, but no dice so far.

---

Clarification edit:

In principle, if I have an origin pixel with colour (R1, G1, B1) and a target pixel with colour (R2, G2, B2), there exists a unique tuple (x, y, z) such that (R2, G2, B2) = (R1, G1, B1) + (x, y, z), right? So what I'd like is a layer that has (x, y, z) for every pixel of the original image plus some way to combine the original layer with this new layer to obtain the final layer.

(And of course (x, y, z) would need to be mod 255 and so would the sum, since negative colour pixels don't exist.)

Of course if you include an alpha there the answer is no longer unique, right, since (x, y, z, 1) is the same as (2x, 2y, 2z, 0.5) in terms of what it adds to the original layer? As I understand it? But I'm fine with assuming alpha = 1 everywhere (and giving the original image a black background if that's necessary) to make the answer unique.

Comment: I'm unsure if it's an exact duplicate, but isn't your question basically the same as [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/145433)? And [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/156976) more recent question which was closed as a duplicate of the first? In other words: I don't think it's possible. ‍♂️

Comment: ermmm... clouds filter and a mask... or clouds filter *on* a mask.

Comment: @Wolff yeah i saw both of those questions but they don't really answer the same thing i think? the more recent one is not what i want because like i said i don't actually care about the "background" parts, and the other one says it's impossible to restore layers if the alpha channel is not 0 or 1 but that's not an issue

in principle, if i have an original pixel with some (R1, G1, B1) and a target pixel with some (R2, G2, B2), there is a unique tuple (x, y, z) such that (R2, G2, B2) = (R1, G1, B1) + (x, y, z). I want a layer that has (x, y, z) for every pixel in the original image

Comment: @Pedro, you say yourself that there is only a unique answer if we assume alpha = 1. But the pixels of the green cloud covering the character must have many different opacities. Also see [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/154536) question. If you have an image which is a blend of a background image and a top image with some alpha, you can recreate the top image *if* you can guess the alpha. But if all pixels have different alphas I don't think it's possible without some AI. Check out my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadsWolff/eoxtnp29/) which automates "unblending".

Comment: That first part of your answer is _exactly_ what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pedro, do you mean the answer to the question I just linked to? That's not my answer. I just got inspired to write the script.

Comment: If you want to do work like this, keep everything on separate layers.  Don't paint anything directly on the original artwork layer. When you have finished save as PSD. That will preserve the layers. It's not possible to recover layers if you flattened an image.

Comment: Do realise that the example image you are using is copyrighted, and anything you post on here [is automatically released in CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). You may want to remove this image and give another example.

Comment: If you want to limber up your brain, imagine a layer which should be placed above the original (brown) image layer with a well selected blending mode. The blending mode is normal.

Comment: What do you mean by "add some tinting"? So you are adding several different layers with different blend modes and expect to be able to reduce them to one single layer with *one* blend mode? Which one? Think of it this way: The second image you have *is* already that image. Just place it above the original with blend mode "normal" and 100% opacity, covering it completely. That's *one* valid solution. Perhaps the only one in this case. I'm not sure what you want makes logically sense. And I still think perhaps your answer can be found in one of the earlier questions I linked to.